# Unterschied zwischen „Achtung!“ und „Vorsicht!“

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „Achtung!“ und „Vorsicht!“?

Welches Wort sollte man z.B. rufen, wenn man in einer Straße ist und es eine Gefahr gibt, oder wenn jemand den Weg versperrt?

Comment: Was sagt Dein Wörterbuch? Im Prinzip eine interessante Frage, aber: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences. Bitte ergänze Deine Ergebnisse. (Du kannst auch auf Englisch fragen, wenn das für Dich einfacher ist.) Herzlich willkommen!

Comment: Okay, ich hab ein Bespiel hinzugefügt. Danke für deinen Rat.

Comment: Speziell in der Seemannssprache gibt es auch noch [„Wahrschau!“](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wahrschau).

Comment: @DavidP.Kendal Super, danke!

Comment: Für mich besteht hier kein Unterschied, solange man es in dieser Form lässt. Zwischen "Achtung" und "**Sei** Vorsichtig" würde ein klarer Unterschied zu sehen sein.

Comment: Die einzig richtige Antwort auf die Frage (was sollte man rufen) ist **Obacht!**

Comment: @Jan: *Obacht* ist Dialekt, soviel sollte man dazusagen.

Comment: @userunknown *Obacht* nur als *Dialektwort* zu klassifizieren greift mE zu kurz. Ich kann mir durchaus Hochdeutsch sprechende Bayern vorstellen, die trotzdem *Obacht* sagen – wie sie auch *heuer* sagen würden.

Comment: @Jan: Da ich eine Zeit in Bayern gelebt habe sage ich auch ab und zu "Obacht", so wie ich auch ab und an "bedankt" sage oder "Na servus!". Die Sprache ist zwar Hochdeutsch, aber die Wörter sind m.E. bayerisch (holländisch, österreicherisch). Duden sagt: Gebrauch: süddeutsch.

Comment: @userunknown Dann meinen wir das gleiche, verwenden aber unterschiedliche Namen dafür.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Achtung

Wenn man eine Person *acht*et, dann respektiert man sie und schenkt ihr Aufmerksamkeit. Und um diese Aufmerksamkeit geht es beim Befehl »Achtung!«. Auch der Ausdruck »auf etwas *Acht* geben« hat mit dieser *Acht*ung zu tun.

Wenn z.B. in einer Kaserne eine Person höheren Rangs einen Raum betritt, in dem sich Soldaten niederen Rangs befinden, ruft der erste, der den hochrangigen Besucher wahrnimmt, laut »Achtung!« und begrüßt den Ankömmling, indem er vor ihm salutiert. Die anderen Soldaten salutieren dann ebenfalls, um dem Besucher ihre Achtung zu zeigen.

Auch diese veraltete Grußfloskel am Ende von Briefen enthält diese Achtung:

> *hoch**achtung**svoll*
>   Dr. Wohlmann

Auch Absätze in Vereinbarungen und Verträgen, die eine besondere Aufmerksamkeit erfordern, werden häufig mit dem Wort »Achtung« eingeleitet.

Der Ausruf »Achtung!« fordert also dazu auf, auf etwas zu achten. Das kann natürlich auch eine drohende Gefahr sein, das muss aber nicht so sein.

### Vorsicht

Wenn jemand dazu aufgefordert wird, sich vorzusehen, dann heißt das, dass eine Gefahr droht, die eine erhöhte Aufmerksamkeit erfordert um sie abzuwenden.

> **Sieh dich vor** vor Blondinen, vor der süssen blonden Gefahr, ...
>   *<sub>(Schlagertext aus dem Jahr 1962, vom Hazy Osterwald Sextett)</sub>*

Man wird mit dem Ausruf »sieh dich vor« aufgefordert, sich vor einer Bedrohung in Acht zu nehmen, also auf sich selbst zu achten.

Wie bei der Achtung wird man auch hier aufgefordert seine Aufmerksamkeit zu erhöhen, in diesem Fall aber ausdrücklich, um eine drohende Gefahr zu erkennen und von sich selbst abzuwenden.

**Nur zur Ergänzung:**
Das Wort »vorsehen« (»sieh dich vor!«), von dem die Vorsicht abstammt, hat noch eine zweite Bedeutung, nämlich »planen«:

> Es ist **vorgesehen**, dass Besucher auf dem Besucherparkplatz parken.

Das dazugehörige Substantiv ist die »*Vorsehung*«. Damit sind die Pläne einer göttlichen Macht gemeint, die das Schicksal einzelner Menschen bestimmen.

Comment: Anmerkung für Anfänger: es steht _süssen_ statt _süßen_, weil es sich um einen schweizerischen Schlagertext handelt.

Comment: @WalterTross: Richtig! Hazy Osterwald war Schweizer, und im Schweizerischen Deutsch gibt es den Buchstaben, der in Österreich »Scharfes S« und in Deutschland »Eszett« heißt, nicht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Der Buchstabe heißt auch in Deutschland "Scharfes S". Zumindest in Bayern, BW, dem Saarland, und weiten Teilen von RLP und NRW. Siehe http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f05d/

Answer (score 2):

Der Ausruf "Vorsicht!" ist eine Aufforderung zur Vorsicht, d.h.

> aufmerksames, besorgtes Verhalten in Bezug auf die Verhütung eines möglichen Schadens <sup>[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vorsicht)</sup>
>
> besonnenes, Gefahren sorgfältig meidendes, wachsames Verhalten, Behutsamkeit <sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Vorsicht)</sup>

Bei "Achtung!" liegen die Dinge etwas komplizierter. *Achtung* (ohne Ausrufezeichen) meint Hoch-/Wertschätzung oder Respekt ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Achtung), [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=achtung)). *Achtung!* als Ruf oder Aufschrift - meist mit Ausrufezeichen - bedeutet hingegen eine Aufforderung zur *Be*achtung der Situation oder dessen, was in der Folge gesagt wird. Hier geht es also um ein allgemeines Erzielen von Aufmerksamkeit.

Da Aufmerksamkeit zu vorsichtigem Verhalten dazugehört, haben beide Ausrufe einen großen Überlappungsbereich von Situation, in denen beide Wörter verwendet werden können. Ich würde tendenziell die Bedrohung als akuter einschätzen, wenn ich "Vorsicht!" höre. Aber ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob das jeder hier so sieht. Wenn also z.B. auf der Straße ein Loch ist, würde ich sagen

> Achtung, da vorn ist eine Grube!

und erst wenn die Person das nicht beachtet und weitergeht

> Vorsicht, du fällst gleich rein!

*Achtung!* kann aber auch in Situationen verwendet werden, wo keine Gefahr droht und *Vorsicht!* ein zu starker Ausdruck wäre, z.B. [*Achtung, Fahrplanänderung!*](https://www.google.com/search?q=achtung+fahrplan%C3%A4nderung).

Comment: Inwiefern droht bei Fahrplanänderungen keine Gefahr - etwa die Gefahr den Zug zu verpassen? Fehlende Achtung gegenüber Autoritätspersonen ist auch mit Gefahren verbunden.