# difference between "sei vorsichtig" and "pass auf dich auf"?

Tags: imperative

Could someone please explain what these two expressions mean? In which circumstances have they usages?

A truck comes over me on a road. In that case would someone call me like following:

> Pass auf dich auf!

Comment: Related: [Unterschied zwischen „Achtung!“ und „Vorsicht!“](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/25047/9551)

Comment: @userunknown in Eile bloß :/ did not understand that, does it mean "loudly"?

Comment: @Dragut: Habe eine Antwort draus gemacht. :) It means, in a hurry, one would use a short form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example: The sentence "Pass auf dich auf" is used when you invited a friend and after a few hours he wants to drive home again.

When he arrives, you will say something like "Wie geht's?" or "Alles klar bei dir?" and when he leaves, you will maybe say "Pass auf dich auf" or "Halt die Ohren steif".

---

"Sei vorsichtig" is mostly used when somebody tells you that he wants to do something dangerous, for example: "Ich geh schon mal in die Küche und schneide die Karotten in Scheiben" - "Ok, aber sei vorsichtig"

---

When a truck is about to run into somebody, you will shout someting like "Achtung!" or "Spring!" or just "Aaaah!" or you will simply pull him away.

Comment: And the Bavarian is calling for *Obacht!* ;)

Answer (score 2):

Man würde in Eile bloß "vorsicht" oder "pass auf" rufen. Vor einer Reise nach Belgien würde man beide längere Versionen benutzen können.

Answer (score 1):

- “sei vorsichtig” - be careful!

Wenn es um eine (potentielle) Gefahr geht.

- “pass auf dich auf” - take care of yourself

Es ist einfach ein freundlicher Wunsch, wenn man sich z.B. verabschiedet.